# How would you go about evaluating $\langle \psi \mid 100 \mid \psi \rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

How would you go about evaluating 
$\langle \psi \mid 100 \mid \psi \rangle$?

I just can't seem to figure this out, and I know it isn't hard.

Comment: Try answering this: what is the (physical) meaning of $\langle\psi|\hat{A}|\psi\rangle$? (where $\hat{A}$ is an arbitrary, hermitian operator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do factor out the 100, that is

$$\langle\psi | 100 |\psi\rangle = 100\langle \psi |\psi\rangle.$$

In general, if $\psi$ is a correctly normalized state we should have $\langle \psi|\psi \rangle = 1$, hence $100\langle\psi|\psi\rangle = 100(1) = 100.$

Edit: Alternatively (more physically?) you can think of $100$ as a Hermitian operator in and of itself, in which case $\langle\psi | 100 |\psi\rangle$ is the expectation value of $100$. Hence, $\langle\psi | 100 |\psi\rangle = 100$ clearly.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking it must be expectation value, so that does it clarify it for me.

Comment: It is an expectation value only in the case when we assume that the vector $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the operator 100 which is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

$$
\left\langle\psi\ |100\,|\,\psi\right\rangle = 100\left\langle\psi\,|\,\psi\right\rangle
$$
I admit to guessing though as I have not seen such notation.  But, my guess is 100 as a scaler can be factored out, or multiply the ket $|\,\psi\rangle$ and then take the inner product of the Bra and Ket (and, the factor of 100 can of course be taken out as I have suggested).  This would be $100\,|\,\psi\,|^2$.

I could be wrong.

Comment: I would be more general. I would consider 100 as a symbolic notation of an operator without implying that the action of 100 is a multiplication of the corresponding number on the vector $|\psi\rangle$. Why can not it be, for instance, a subtraction of the number.